# Geometrical or Physical significance (interpretation) of the inner-product $\langle A,B \rangle := Trace (AB^t)$ over $M_n(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, soft-question, inner-products, trace

$\langle A,B \rangle := Trace (AB^t)$ is an inner product over the vector space $M_n(\mathbb R)$ of all real matrices of size $n$ , I would like to know whether this inner-product has any Geometrical or Physical significance (interpretation) or not ? Please shed some light . Thanks in advance

Comment: for example, if one of the  operators is the density matrix $A=\rho$ and the other one is an observable B, this inner product will give you the average value of B, $<B>=Tr(\rho B)$. Note that the transpose vanishs, because our observables have to be orthogonal/hermitian

Answer (score 1):

For this inner product, the squared norm of a matrix will be the sum of all squared coefficients of the matrix, so this norm, and the inner product, correspond to the canonical inner product and $2$-norm on $\mathbf{R}^{n^2}$, when  the latter is identified with the $M_n (\mathbf{R})$. This is the simple euclidian norm !

Comment: Well , but that is just the definition ....

Comment: Yes, but I thought you knew the geometric interpretation of the $2$-norm on $\mathbf{R}^N$. Don't you ?